# refresh token of docusign in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, docusignapi

I am using docusign api in my spring boot application, for quick start docusign provides a token which expires in 8 hours, that is impractical.
so how to refresh this token when it becomes not useful? 
thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Spring Boot DocuSign code example](https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-java-auth-code-grant).

It uses Spring Boot security to implement the OAuth Authorization Code Grant flow.

The token then lasts 8 hours. To refresh via Spring Boot Security, see this [blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20180218075622/https://jugbd.org/2017/09/19/implementing-oauth2-spring-boot-spring-security/) -- note the `refreshToken` settings.

Also see [this article.](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth2-remember-me)